# d3 iterate over nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have json data which has the following structure:

```
var data = {
  "from": 1457823600000,
  "to": 1458687600000,
  "equipments": [
    {
      "name": "Equipment1",
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "action1",
          "start": 1458035704183,
          "end": 1458122104234,
          "color": "green"
        },
        {
          "name": "action2",
          "start": 1458035704268,
          "end": 1458294904268,
          "color": "red"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Equipment2",
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "action3",
          "start": 1458208504268,
          "end": 1458381304268,
          "color": "blue"
        },
        {
          "name": "action4",
          "start": 1458122104268,
          "end": 1458467704268,
          "color": "yellow"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

On the d3 y-axis it should look like this:

```
Equipment 1    |
    action1    |
    action2    |
               |
Equipment 2    |
    action3    |
    action4    |
               |
               -----------------------------
```

Now my d3 looks like this

```
var equipments = svg.selectAll("equipments")
                .data(data.equipments)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                  .attr("x", ...)
                  .attr("y", ...)
                  .text(name);
```

I can iterate over the 2 equipments (`Equipment1` and `Equipment2`) but how to deal with the children of the equipments?

Answer (score 1):

This could be solve like this I guess:

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');
var equipments = svg.selectAll("equipments")
                .data(data.equipments)
                .enter()
                .append("g");

equipments.append("text")
                .text(function(d){return d.name});

equipments.append("g").selectAll("actions")
                .data(function(d) { return d.actions })
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name});
```

The output has no position (x or y) so its stacked, but if you inspect the element you see the desired structure:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <text>Equipment1</text>
        <g>
            <text>action1</text>
            <text>action2</text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <text>Equipment2</text>
        <g>
            <text>action3</text>
            <text>action4</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I like using `<g>` which is usually very usefull in practice, even if, in your case, it is not mandatory.
(See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0ccuw1r/))

Comment: does this solved your problem? may you validate this anwser?